# How to check if list of strings all match the same regex in multiple regexes js_regex

Tags: python, regex

I have following regexes / code snippet:

```
import js_regex

# I got 2 regexes
a = js_regex.compile(r"^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]$")
b = js_regex.compile(r"^\$[A-Z]{3}$")

# which I can test like this:
if a.match("BE46138E7195"):
    print("match a")

if b.match("$USD"):
    print("match b")

if not a.match("BDDD"):
    print("not matching works")

# ab: third pattern to combine a and b
# first question: is this possible without making a new js_regex?
ab = js_regex.compile(r"^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]||$[A-Z]{3}$")
if ab.match("BE46138E7195"):
    print("match ab")
if ab.match("$USD"):
    print("match ab")
if not ab.match("BDDD"):
    print("not matching works")
```

So as you can see, 2 regexes and already a first question (see snippet).
But the main question. Suppose I have a list of strings:

```
["BED", "KLO", "BN"]
```

I want to check if ALL strings in that list are matching with my `ab` regex.
BUT: it is ok if they are ALL not matching, like:

```
["A", "B", "C"]
```

is ok, because they are all not matching. So I have 2 groups that are possible:
[AB] and [not AB].

What's the best way to tackle this?

Comment: I understand `["BED", "KLO", "BN"]` contain non-matching entries, hence it is `True`. Same with `["A", "B", "C"]`, it is True. `["xxx", "$AUD"]` is `False` as `xxx` does not match and the `$AUD` matches. `['XX46434G8630', '$USD', 'XX46434V7047']` is `True` as all match. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Per each of the strings check (the AB check) I would go this way:

```
if a.match(txt) and b.match(txt):
   print("We have a match!")
```

Now, if you want to check if *whole* list matches:

```
def ab_match(txt):
   return a.match(txt) and b.match(txt)


list_res = [ab_match(txt) for txt in alist]

all_match = all(list_res)

all_no_match = all((not res for res in list_res))
```

How does it work:

`all` - returns `True` only if all of the values in the iterator have Boolean value of `True`

So, in case of checking if none of the strings are matching you have to first revert the result per each `alist` list element.

Separate question if you can combine both regexes. Essentially, you can: for regex A or B you can construct a regex A|B. Typically, (A)|(B) to ensure that the alternative is between the whole regexes not parts of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ab` pattern is wrong, you have a `||` inside that allows an empty string match, you need just one `|` to define an alternation.

Next, you did not group the patterns correctly, you need to wrap the `p1|p2` with `^(?:p1|p2)$`.

So, if you wanted to declare `ab` pattern you would use

```py
ab = js_regex.compile(r"^(?:[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]|\$[A-Z]{3})$")
```

You can use this pattern like this:

```py
def validate(arr):
    return (all(map(ab.search, arr)) or all(map(lambda x: not ab.search(x), arr)) )
```

See the Python demo:

```py
import js_regex, re
 
a = js_regex.compile(r"^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]$")
b = js_regex.compile(r"^\$[A-Z]{3}$")
ab = re.compile(f'{a.pattern}|{b.pattern}') # Build the ab pattern from the two above

def validate(arr):
    return (all(map(ab.search, arr)) or all(map(lambda x: not ab.search(x), arr)) )
 
l1 = ["BED", "KLO", "BN"]
l2 = ["A", "B", "C"]
l3 = ["xxx", "$AUD"]
l4 = ['XX46434G8630', '$USD', 'XX46434V7047']
print(validate(l1), validate(l2), validate(l3), validate(l4), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
True
```

Comment: This is resulting False when you combine a with b, for example:
ok = ["XX46434G8630", "$USD", "XX46434V7047"]

Comment: @sg_sg94 I changed the answer. I think it is really easier to follow your logic with a new regex that includes both alternatives. You may use the existing `a` and `b` regex objects to build the new one.